# Javascript 'New' object's 'this' in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this

I am working through Marc Wandscheider's 'Learning Node.JS'. I have copied this code for a class and call;

```
let fs = require('fs');
function FileObject() {
    this.filename = '';
    this.file_exists = function(callback) {
        console.log('About to open: ' + this.filename);
        fs.open(this.filename, 'r', function(err, handle) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Can\'t open: ' + this.filename);
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            fs.close(handle, function() {});
            callback(null, true);
        });
    };
}
let fo = new FileObject();
fo.filename = 'file_that_does_not_exist';
fo.file_exists((err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('\nError opening file: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
    console.log('file exists!!!');
});
```

When run it outputs

```
About to open: file_that_does_not_exist
Can't open: undefined
```

The undefined is because of the async nature of the `fs.open()` method. The author corrects this by adding a variable to store this in `let self = this;`

I would like to use `bind(this);` instead, but cannot work out how to do it! Is there an alternative to using the `self` hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you can call `.bind` on the function you pass to `fs.open` in order to correctly bind `this`:

```
fs.open(this.filename, 'r', function (err, handle) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Can\'t open: ' + this.filename);
        callback(err);
        return;
    }
    fs.close(handle, function() {});
    callback(null, true);
}.bind(this));  // <-- here
```

An alternative to using `self` or `.bind` is to use an arrow function, which provides lexical scoping:

```
let fs = require('fs');
function FileObject() {
    this.filename = '';
    this.file_exists = function(callback) {
        console.log('About to open: ' + this.filename);
        //                            right here --v
        fs.open(this.filename, 'r', (err, handle) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Can\'t open: ' + this.filename);
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            fs.close(handle, function() {});
            callback(null, true);
        });
    };
}
let fo = new FileObject();
fo.filename = 'file_that_does_not_exist';
fo.file_exists((err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('\nError opening file: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
    console.log('file exists!!!');
});
```

Browser friendly example:

```js
let fs = {
  open: function(filename, type, callback) {
    callback(new Error());
  }
};

function FileObject() {
  this.filename = '';
  this.file_exists = function(callback) {
    console.log('About to open: ' + this.filename);
    //                            right here --v
    fs.open(this.filename, 'r', (err, handle) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Can\'t open: ' + this.filename);
        callback(err);
        return;
      }
      fs.close(handle, function() {});
      callback(null, true);
    });
  };
}
let fo = new FileObject();
fo.filename = 'file_that_does_not_exist';
fo.file_exists((err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('\nError opening file: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
  console.log('file exists!!!');
});
```

Comment: That was a quick answer. Yes that it the way I want to do it! Thank you.(I'll mark it as the answer in 9 . mins)

Comment: Just to add a little bit of context - arrow functions were added to Node in version 4, hence why the book referenced in the original post doesn't use them.